# IE8 Printing website zoomed in

Tags: internet-explorer, printing-web-page

I'm having a particularly fun issue with IE8.

The website prints fine in firefox, chrome, ie9, but when printed from IE8, the page is about 50% larger than it should be, causing the right side to be cut off.

This can be solved by scaling down the zoom from the print preview to 70%, but the client isn't satisfied with this solution.

I haven't had any luck finding much info, or similar problems via google and SO.

Does anyone have any suggestions for me?

It's also hard to troubleshoot printing from IE8 when you're working on a mac :( (client brought up the issue).

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

I was having the same problem (only with IE8) and realized that IE8 seemed to be zooming based on the width of the first div it encountered. In my case, the first div was 456px wide, while the second was 920px. The second div was therefore cut off on the right.

My solution was to add an empty div (920px wide, 1px high) before all others. That fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

you need to make a special css or query to IE8, it's normal.

Comment: I tried the "zoom" property in css for IE8 only.

I set it to 70% and it resulted in the page printing so small it was just a few dots on the page.

Comment: IE8 is problematic. you need specific a tag only for that.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean gmendes. 
I had set up an IE8 only stylesheet, and added the zoom property, which caused the website to print extremely small (zoom: 70%).

It actually looks like the "shrink to fit" feature in IE8 is not running when it prints.