# zoom in the printing page in IE8

Tags: printing, internet-explorer-8, zooming

I have a problem with the printing page (zoom) in IE8

Sometimes the printing page it shown in 50% and others times in 100%, I don't have control on it.

I have tried the solutions from [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13163321/ie8-printing-website-zoomed-in), but is the same, it doesn't work.

I tried with this code in my print.css ():

```
@viewport {
    zoom: 1;
}
```

but, it doesn't work.

Please, some idea?

Comment: I forgot to mention that I use Bootstrap 3.x

Answer (score 0):

Ok I found a solution.
Finally I never could control the zoom in the IE8, but I could know when IE decides put zoom to a website, in my case was 750px wide.

I was using:

```
<div class="container">..</div>
```

and this class put a width fixed, that exceeds the 750px.

Then, I changed it to:

```
<div class="container-fluid">..</div>
```

and css I put:

```
.container-fluid { width:750px; }
```

that is to say, removed the responsive web design in IE8